# Failed to execute git command in Docker container using fig/crane

Tags: git, containers, docker, bower, git-submodules

I use [crane](https://github.com/michaelsauter/crane) to orchestrate my containers and I've got a git submodule for my project sources (a NodeJS app). When I run up my containers when it tries to `bower install` in my project root this error occurs:

```
bower jquery#~2.1.1            ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: Not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/src/web
```

Here is my `crane.yml` config file:

```
containers:
    db:
        dockerfile: images/db
        image: project/db
        run:
            detach: true
    web:
        dockerfile: images/web
        image: project/web
        run:
            volume: ["src/web:/src"]
            publish: ["8000:8000"]
            link: ["db:mongo"]
            detach: true
```

And here is my `fig.yml`

```
db:
    build: images/db
web:
    build: images/web
    volumes:
      - src/web:/src
    links:
      - db:mongo
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

The weird thing is when I set my volume outside the current directory (`../myproject` for example) it works. But I really need to have a submodule in my repository

**Edit**

It doesn't work if I use command line. So it's not related to fig or crane but maybe to how Docker, bower or git work.

**Note**

- I'm on Archlinux
- I also tried with [Docker fig](https://github.com/docker/fig), It generates the same error

Thanks for your help !

Comment: have you issued `git submodule init`, `git submodule update`?

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that the repo has not initialized submodules correctly. Each of git submodules has its own independent repository, and `git submodule` machinery creates a clone of it inside `.git/modules/` subdirectory, and the module's working directory refers to that cloned repository. So the error you've encountered means that the repository wasn't properly cloned, either because you've forgotten to do this, or because it can't be initialized for some reason

Comment: I did a `git submodule add git@github.com:kokaz/myrepo src/web`, `git submodule init`, `git submodule update`. It works well when I run my container with the Docker CLI even if it's a submodule but not through my orchestrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your using `git submodule`, you will find a `.git` file referring to the git directory, something like that:

```
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/src/web
```

When you launch a Docker container you're putting your `.git` file without the `.git/` folder so when the container launch a `git` command in the submodule, it try to access git objects which are not accessible.

**The solution**

Rename the `.git` file temporarly or not using `git submodule`

Comment: Is there any clean way to do this ? I mean, I have a bunch of gateways as submodules I don't want to rename their .git every time I need to install a new git repository.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this problem if you are using a `git submodule` inside a `docker container` and running git or bower. In your `Dockerfile`, place the following to fix the git references:

```
    # git submodules reference fix
    ENV GIT_DIR=/path/to/git/submodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what @kokaz described, but I found a workaround. In your Dockerfile:

```
# Initialize an empty git repo.
RUN git init /fakegit

# Tell git to use that repo instead of the .git file in the submodule.
ENV GIT_DIR=/fakegit/.git
```

If you're using docker compose just add the env var to `environment`:

```yaml
environment:
  GIT_DIR: /fakegit/.git
```

Or if this causes problems you can instead create a file containing `gitdir: /fakegit/.git` and mount it as a volume on top of original .git file:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./.git_override:/app/.git
```